# Execute SQL command and output result to DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ms-access

I am trying to execute an SQL command on an Access Database over an OleDbConnection using C# and use that information to fill a DataGridView on a windows form. I have opened the connection, stated the query, and executed it, but I cannot find how to output the results to the DataGridView on the windows form (named dataOutput).

```
    private void Query()
    {
        string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM RetentionTable " +
            "WHERE [DateTime] BETWEEN '" + getDateTimeFrom("") + "' AND '" + getDateTimeTo("") + "'";

        string ConnectionPath = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=RetentionDB.mdb";

        try
        {
            OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionPath);
            DataSet objDataSet = new DataSet();
            OleDbDataAdapter objDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();

            if (cn.State.Equals(ConnectionState.Closed))
            {
                cn.Open();
            }

            OleDbCommand OleDbSearch = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, cn);
            OleDbSearch.ExecuteNonQuery();

            objDataAdapter.Fill(objDataSet);
            dataOutput.DataSource = objDataSet;
            cn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace.ToString());
        }

    }
```

From what I can see, the query is being executed correctly, but the issue comes when trying to use the objDataAdapter.Fill. I guess I am not understanding how to fill the DataSet with the output from the query. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few comments:

1. Your query is subject to SQL injection. Use a parameterised query instead.
2. You don't need to open/close the connection; the `DataAdapter` will do that for you.
3. You should wrap the `OleDbConnection` and `OleDbCommand` objects in a `using` block to ensure that their resources are cleaned up.
4. You don't need to call `ExecuteNonQuery`, or any other `Execute...` method on the command;
5. You need to assign the command to the `SelectCommand` property of the `OleDbDataAdapter`, or pass it to the constructor.

Try something like this:

```
private void Query()
{
   const string ConnectionPath = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=RetentionDB.mdb";

   try
   {
      using (var cn = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionPath))
      using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM RetentionTable WHERE [DateTime] BETWEEN ? And ?"))
      {
         // Parameter names don't matter; OleDb uses positional parameters.
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p0", getDateTimeFrom(""));
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", getDateTimeTo(""));

         var objDataSet = new DataSet();
         var objDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
         objDataAdapter.Fill(objDataSet);

         dataOutput.DataSource = objDataSet;
      }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
      MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace.ToString());
   }
}
```

Comment: SO I did this and it seems to be executing correctly, but there is no data being shown in the grid view. It just shows no entries. I have AutoGenerateColuns = true, but there is no data. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Replace with `ExecuteDataSet method`

```
..
OleDbSearch.ExecuteDataSet();
objDataAdapter.Fill(objDataSet);
dataOutput.DataSource = objDataSet;
...
```

I suggest you to set your close connection in using blok or try with Finally of your try catch

Best practise

```
 using( var cn = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionPath))
 {
    ... 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also load the data into a DataTable and point the DataGridView to the table:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Fill(OleDbSearch.ExecuteReader());
dataOutput.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not execute `OleDbSearch.ExecuteNonQuery` this is used only for queries that modify data (INSERT/UPDATE). Instead assign you command to dataadatper:

```
objDataAdapter.SelectCommand = OleDbSearch;
```

And then do your `Fill` and DataSource assignment.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to retrieve a DataSet using an `OleDbDataAdapter` is to associate the `OleDbCommand` to the `SelectCommand` property of the OleDbDataAdapter. You simply pass the OleDbCommand to the constructor of the OleDbDataAdapter.

Also your code should use a parameterized query for the text of the command, not a string concatenation. Using parameterized query allows you to avoid Sql Injections and the correct parsing of your text, date, decimals variable is done by the framework code.

```
   string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM RetentionTable WHERE [DateTime] BETWEEN ? AND ?";
   string ConnectionPath = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=RetentionDB.mdb";
   try
   {
        using(OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionPath))
        using(OleDbCommand OleDbSearch = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, cn))
        using(OleDbDataAdapter objDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(OleDbSearch))
        {
            OleDbSearch.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", getDateTimeFrom(""));
            OleDbSearch.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", getDateTimeTo(""));
            DataSet objDataSet = new DataSet();
            cn.Open();
            objDataAdapter.Fill(objDataSet);
            dataOutput.DataSource = objDataSet;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
         MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace.ToString());
    }
```

The [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) is another point to take note. This will ensure a correct closing and disposing of the connection, command and adapter also in case of exceptions.

Comment: This is then giving me the error showing "The SelectCommand property has not been initialized before calling "Fill".

Comment: That's really strange. As you can see from the docs here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wz82t73.aspx passing the OleDbCommand to the constructor of the OleDbDataAdapter assigns the SelectCommand property