# Read data from database OleDB MS access

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

Can anyone guide me on how to read data from database

Here is some of my code

```
oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from userdetails where date <='"+DateTime.Now+"'", cn);
oda.Fill(dt);
if (dt.Rows.Count == 3) 
{
    MessageBox.Show("You have notification on due date"); 
}
```

The code above only will pop up message box if the date data in my userdetails table less or equal then current date now. So, how can I make more reasonable like notify the user 3 days early before the due date. Can anyone guide me?

Comment: Convert DateTime type to SQL DateTime type. Use SqlCommand Parameters

Comment: It's ok if I'm using MS Access as database and put SqlCommand Parameters?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17707267/execute-sql-command-and-output-result-to-datagridview-in-c-sharp
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbw6zyha(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: not so understand for those code because I'm still learning...